# Timetracking between actions with Matomo on an single-site angular app

Tags: angular, matomo

Is it possible to track the min/max/avg time between actions?

I've got a single-site-page and want to track the time to edit values.

1. Klick Edit
2. ..edit Values
3. Save Changes

How to track the time between 1 and 3?

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible with some sort of centralized state management and hooking into the events you're wanting to track.

### Action Tracking Service

You could use a service that's available throughout your app to track actions (name, timestamp) and expose an interface to interact with. The following is oversimplified and could easily be refactored to use observables and include more safeguards if additional reactivity is required like updating action times in another part of the app.

```
export class ActionTrackingService {
 private actions = {}; // could be any storage type like a Map
 private timing = []; // could be an observable(s) for better reactivity

 add(id: string) {
  this.actions[id] = new Date();
 }

 complete(id: string) {
  const action = this.actions[id];

  const diff = Math.abs(new Date() - action);

  delete this.actions[id]; // optional clean up

  this.timings.push(diff) // could also track the action id to differentiate the time between action types instead of all actions. 

  return diff;
 }

 getMin() { }
 getMax() { }
 getAvg() { }
}
```

### Events

1. Click Edit - if a button triggers this, you can hook into that event and log your action event to the Action Tracking Service.
2. Save changes - if this is a button on a form, you can add another hook to this click event and call something like `astService.complete(actionName)` and have it find the name in the service, calculate the time difference from when it was first stored, and return it or update your calculations.